# Group module morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Define $d_1:Z[G]\to Z[G]$ morphism by the following.

Take basis element $\sigma\in G$. Define $d_1(\sigma)=1-\sigma$. Then $d_1$ is a $G-$module morphism.

$\textbf{Q:}$ I tried to verify $g\in G$ $d_1(g\sigma)=gd_1(\sigma)$. However, I got $d_1(g\sigma)=1-g\sigma$ whereas $gd_1(\sigma)=g(1-\sigma)$. I cannot even match the basis in the image. Have I done something wrong here? I would expect this definition should give me $G-$module morphism as I was trying to check standard free resolution of $Z$ is a complex. And I am stucked at the first step.

Ref: Neukirch Bonn Lectures Chpt 1. Sec 2.

Comment: No, $d_1$ is not a map $\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right] \to \mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]$ in [Neukirch's Bonn lectures](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/~schmidt/Neukirch-en/). Rather, it is a map $X_1 \to X_0$, where $X_1 = \bigoplus_{g \in G} \mathbb{Z}\left[G\right] \left(g\right)$ is some sort of "$\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]\left[G\right]$". Read "$d_1\left(\sigma\right)$" as "$d_1$ of $1_{\mathbb{Z}\left[G\right]} \left(\sigma\right)$".

Comment: @darijgrinberg How should I interpret $G-$module map then? He claimed that $d_i$ differential maps are $G-$module maps. And his map differs from his cohomology for number fields. It also differs from brown's cohomology of groups.